# Can I get a HTTPS certificate for an IP Address?

Tags: networking, ssl-certificate, ip, https

Ok so here is the use case:
I have built a dns based ad and content blocker. I have used dnsmasq as dns forwarder for it. If the domain user is trying to visit is blacklisted than dnsmasq will resolve the domain to another ip address which hosts an HTML page which informs user of the restriction. This works for http domains but does not work for domains using https and hsts.

Comment: you could install a top level cert, on all the client machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can request certs for an IP.  No it will not work the way you want, the IP must be the host header (https://192.0.2.10).

If you control all clients you can resign all websites with a private certificate authority that you control, similar to systems like "Content Keeper"

Comment: So any other solution?

Comment: Yes, don't listen on 443, blocked connections don't have content warnings

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to reliably redirect https traffic.  I work for a large wireless provider and we would absolutely love to be able to do so - primary use case being to redirect our customers to a purchase page when they've used up all their data (much like we do in the case of http traffic),  Our only recourse in the case of https is to block the connection and use an out of band message (primarily SMS) to notify the customer.

Comment: That's the point....

Comment: The question which arises in my mind is that if a website does not use HSTS than the client web browser connects to its server using HTTP first and is then redirected to HTTPS. Before making the first HTTP connection browser will have to perform DNS lookup, If I go by that logic then the browser should get connected to the fake IP send by DNSmasq using HTTP only. However, I still get an invalid cert error.

Comment: Close.... Port...443 on your destination IP for dnsmasq.  301 and HSTS Preload are cached.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect a user (via DNS rewrite, for example), then what you are attempting to do is to create a (legitimate) Man-in-the-Middle (MitM). In effect, you are pretending to be someone you are not.

In terms of HTTPS, there is no nice works-for-everyone solution. The only feasible solution is to have something that creates certificates on the fly with its own issuing certificate (*not* trusted by any CA), and then cause this certificate to be trusted (by process of importing) into all your client devices, so they see your MitM as valid.

... excepting of course HSTS. When you do this MitM thing, you have to maintain a list of exceptions, or automatically detect when not to do a MitM, or you will break things like Mobile / Banking apps that use HSTS / certificate pinning.

This is what the large Next-Generation Firewalls do (eg. FortiNet, Palo-Alto and others).

*However*, since you say you are using a DNS based approach, rather than resolve to an IP address which you then pretend to be, you might instead consider rewriting it to 0.0.0.0 (or :: in the case of an IPv6 AAAA record). That would then cause the connection to immediately fail.

This is just like putting the following in your /etc/hosts file.

```
0.0.0.0 backend1.example.com
```

I use this trick if I have a service (say a reverse-proxy) that is wanting to talk to one of more backends, and I need to take one of the backends out quickly (perhaps because there is a network issue and there are lots of ARP timeouts, for example). Its good because it will cause the underlying 'connect' request to fail on the client itself (no network IO required).

Comment: I am using 0.0.0.0 for blocking ads. The HTML page is only displayed when user tries to visit a domain which has been explicitly blocked like an adult website. In such a case the webpage tells user that the domain he is trying to visit falls in adult category and is blocked

Comment: My advice remains the same with regard to HTTPS